Problem with autherization log in by another app (android deeplink) MAUI Project
I am working on MAUI app and want to login by another app Zalo (on Android)
I have a WebView to call zalo api for login. A login screen shows up on webview with a button "Login with Zalo app"
When I clicked on it, the zalo app opened, but seem like it crash somehow and return to my app with nothing. It worked successfully if I logged in with zalo by using QR of Zalo on website, but I need to log in by zalo app in android device.
Here is the document for Zalo app developer: https://developers.zalo.me/docs/sdk/android-sdk/tong-quan
ZaloView.Navigating += WebViewOnNavigating;
public async void WebViewOnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    var uri = e.Url;
    if (uri.Contains("code=")) {
        //Expect the zalo app to return an url with code=... to continute
    }
    else if (uri.StartsWith("zalo://login/"))
    {
        //Here to open the zalo app, but I don't know how to get the result back
        var canOpen = await Launcher.TryOpenAsync(uri);
        if(!canOpen)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Zalo app can not be opened", "OK");
        }
    }
}

I also edit AndroidManifest.xml:
<application android:name="com.zing.zalo.zalosdk.oauth.ZaloSDKApplication" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.zing.zalo.zalosdk.oauth.BrowserLoginActivity" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="zalo-2283240503624270354" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<queries>
<intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="zalo" />
</intent>
<package android:name="com.zing.zalo" />
</queries>


but seem like it crash somehow What was the actual error? As in, please quote the error text/exception and stacktrace in your post. People cannot help you if you do not post the actual error message.
